# Coded Automatic UITest + Windows Form + Exe-file?

Tags: winforms, testing, user-interface, exe

I've been trying to make a exe-file of the Auto Coded UI so I can have this running on several computers over a night!

This is was I have done so far:

- Successfully created a automatic UI code that tests another client (Another project)
- Created a simple GUI (Windows form with a button)
- Referred Auto UI to the WinForm Project (Changed the Target Framework to make it work)

But now I've encountered a problem that says:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm guessing that the problem is that it can't find the client's window. But don't know how to "link" these together! :(

I hope there is a way of fixing this (easy?) problem!

Thanks in advance,

/ZXangan

Answer (score 1):

To run a test to a target machine the proposed way is to install a test agent in the target machine that will run your tests. That way the agent will install whatever is needed to run the tests in the target machine. Then from VS you can manage it and send tests to it.